# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysnmp.hlapi'; 'pysnmp' is not a package

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm trying to import elements from hlapi using

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
```

but keep getting this
error

```
No module named 'pysnmp.hlapi'; 'pysnmp' is not a package"
```

I've the following version installed:

```
Name: pysnmp
Version: 4.4.12
Summary: SNMP library for Python
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: python -m pip install pysnmp

Comment: What's the full command line you used to execute the sample code? And what is the full command line you used to install PySNMP? Almost every machines has multiple Python versions installed, so the two steps you used might be of two different Python versions.

Comment: Very likely you wrote a `pysnmp.py` file for testing. However, you should use a name like `test-pysnmp.py`.